# Check if there exists derivative

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f: R^2 \rightarrow R$ so that:
$$f(x,y)= \begin{cases}\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2} (x,y) \ne (0,0)\\ 0   \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (x,y)= (0,0)\end{cases}$$
Check if there exists:
$ \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}(0,0)$

The problem is that I don't really know what exactly I have to do and how to do it, so I would really appreciate any hints. (I already derived the function).

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{2y^3-2x^2y}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$

$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}=\frac{(6y^2-2x^2)(x^2+y^2)-4y(2y^3-2x^2y)}{(x^2+y^2)^4}$

**EDIT:**
I also checked that $ \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}$ is not continuous in $(0,0)$ (and that there's no limit there)

Comment: First part: Assume $y$ is fixed and derive to $x$.

Answer (score 2):

You can work with the definition at (0,0). That is, 
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(0+h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}$ or
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(0,0+h)-f(0,0)}{h}$ and so on.
So since $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=0$ , we have
$\frac{\partial ^{2}f}{\partial x\partial y}(0,0)=\frac{\partial f_{x}}{\partial y}(0,0)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f_{x}(0,0+h)-f_{x}(0,0)}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}2/h=\infty$ .
So it does not exist.

Comment: so $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{2y^3-2x^2y}{(x^2+y^2)^2} (x,y)\ne (0,0)\\ 0   \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (x,y)= (0,0)\end{cases}$ and later on I check if there exists derrivative, the usual way, yes?